# How can I set Windows "DPI-scaling overrides" via a script?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, wxpython, dpi

We have a Python-based application with a WxPython GUI that we create for multiple operating systems. In Windows 10, at least in my environment (inside a VM on a high resolution monitor), the text elements in the interface are blurry.  I can improve the appearance by setting the Windows application [DPI-scaling override](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/). However, the only way I have found so far is to do it manually from the Windows file explorer interface.

[image]

My question: **Is there a way to set this property from the command line**, so that I can script this as part of building our application?

Answer (score 0):

in python code:

```
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```

[Consider this from the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness).