# How to fix blurry text in WxPython controls on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, wxpython, dpi

We have a Python-based application written with WxPython 4 that we build for multiple operating systems, including Windows. In Windows 10, at least in my environment (inside a VM on a high resolution monitor), the text elements in the interface are blurry:

[image]

I can improve the situation somewhat by [setting the Windows DPI-scaling override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884217/how-can-i-set-windows-dpi-scaling-overrides-via-a-script) on the application.  This is indirect and suboptimal, and it seems like there should be a way to do it from WxPython more directly.  However, I have not found a way to do it.

Is there any way to set DPI scaling from WxPython, or otherwise fix blurry text on Windows in WxPython 4 directly from within the application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [a message from Python Issue Tracker](https://bugs.python.org/msg317775) and what I tried in [the wxPython official Hello World, Part 2 example](https://www.wxpython.org/pages/overview/#hello-world) ([helloworld2.py](https://www.wxpython.org/listings/helloworld2.py.html)), adding following code to your program should work:

```
import ctypes
try:
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
except:
    pass
```